# How to remove zeros from a column in db2 table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a column with data zeros after 6th column

i want to remove the leading zero after the 6th pipe in the data.

Please let me know if there is any way to do it. I tried to use `substr` with `Trim` but its not working.

Comment: `after the 6th pipe` ... you lost me at the _first_ pipe, because it is not a good idea to store delimited data in a single SQL column.  While you may want to format your data a certain way, you would be wise to first _normalize_ the table and each delimited value into a separate _column_.

Comment: Once you get the sixth value into a separate column, you can easily remove the zeroes by casting that value to a number, and then back to text again if you really need text.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your column is called `COL` something like the following should work:

```
CONCAT(SUBSTR(1,INSTR(COL,'|', 1,5)), LTRIM(SUBSTR(INSTR(COL,'|', 1,5)+1)),'0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your current data that you need to only replace every occurrence of `|00` with `|`, You can achieve thing using `REPLACE` function.

```
    SELECT 'TMB|MLE020828585|74384911WA3S|="''07300058"|74384911|0013' AS Current_String,
           replace('TMB|MLE020828585|74384911WA3S|="''07300058"|74384911|0013', '|00', '|') AS result_String
```

You can replace hard-coded value in above with your column name.

The above query generate result as below.

```
Current_String                                               |                     result_String
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TMB|MLE020828585|74384911WA3S|="'07300058"|74384911|0013     |   TMB|MLE020828585|74384911WA3S|="'07300058"|74384911|13
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @RuchikaMishra: You can have a look at `LOCATE` function in combination with `REPLACE`. I don't have db2 environment right now to simulate it. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1015483. If this helps, don't forget to accept the answer and upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

Oleg was correct in utilizing INSTR(), that is how I would do it.  He was missing some arguments, though.  Also, I wasn't able to get ltrim to work, so I cast it to an int instead.  I tested and updated my table with your data using:

UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = Substr(mycolumn , 1, Instr(mycolumn , '|', 1, 5))
  || CAST(Substr(mycolumn , Instr(mycolumn , '|', 1, 5) + 1) AS INT)